# typescript syntax for declaring type inside object

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I have an interface for icecream and it looks like so:

```
interface Icecream {
  name: string
  sorbet?: boolean
}
```

Now I want to create an object which contains a property **icecreams**, and I want that property to be **an array of type Icecream**. How can I tell Typescript that, since the colon : notation is already used for assignment?

```
 const myFavs = {
    icecreams: [
      {
        name: 'Vanilla',
        sorbet: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Strawberry',
        sorbet: true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You type the `myFavs` variable:

```
const myFavs: {
     icecreams: Icecream[]
 } = {
    icecreams: [
      {
        name: 'Vanilla',
        sorbet: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Strawberry',
        sorbet: true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or use a type alias to make it more readable:

```
type objectWithIceCreamsArrayProperty = {
    icecreams: Icecream[]
}

const myFavs: objectWithIceCreamsArrayProperty = {
    icecreams: [
        {
            name: 'Vanilla',
            sorbet: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Strawberry',
            sorbet: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is

```
const myFavs = {
   icecreams: [
     {
       name: 'Vanilla',
       sorbet: false
     },
     {
       name: 'Strawberry',
       sorbet: true
     }
   ] as Icecream[]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across another way: add brackets around the key plus type, like so:

```
const myFavs = {
    [icecreams: Icecream[]]: [
      {
        name: 'Vanilla',
        sorbet: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Strawberry',
        sorbet: true
      }
    ]
  }
```

This seems to be the most concise and readable syntax so far, not sure when it was added to typescript or if has always been there:)